# How to include or reference libraries in own library

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

I'm writing my first library in .NET core and it works fine, but if I include it in another project it throws errors that the NuGet packages are missing ("Could not load file or assembly"). Is there any way to include them in the dll of my library or at least mark them as required so I don't have to run the application that is using the library multiple times to find out which packages are missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read about the [dependencies element in the .nuspec reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#dependencies-element).

Comment: As far as i understand it .nuspec adds dependencies for nuget packages. I'm not trying to build a nuget package, just a single or multiple .dll files.

Comment: Sorry... you mentioned NuGet packages as dependencies; I assumed you were building a NuGet package of your own. NuGet deals with transitive dependencies such as this. If you're just putting the assembly on disk somewhere and referring to it there, there's no location metadata for the dependency.

Comment: If adding a reference to your library requires references to NuGet packages, you have to add those references yourself or create it as a NuGet package. If it's for personal use only, you have options. You could configure a folder as a NuGet repository. This will allow you to create your own NuGet packages without publishing to nuget.org or otherwise making them public. Or, you could create a blank MVC project, add the [NuGet.Server](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Server/) package, build, and deploy. Locations can be configured within the IDE or in nuget.config in the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the dependencies, in VS you can right click on the project and publish it.
In the publish setting select the Publish Method to File System (so that you can collect your all dlls) and provide the target location and click on next. In next windows, select deployment mode as **Self-Contained**.

After publish process complete, you will find all the Dlls in the target location. [image]